# WinAPI SetDeskWallpaper

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi, windows-10

I have noticed some strange behavior with the `SystemParamatersInfoA()` function on Windows 10, specifically when modifying the Desktop Wallpaper.

I have the following code, which used to work fine on Windows XP:

```
string wallpaperStr = "C:\\wallpaper.bmp";

bool out = SystemParametersInfoA(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER,0,
(PVOID)wallpaperStr.c_str(), SPIF_SENDCHANGE | SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
```

A simpler recreation of this issue can be done by using the following code:

```
bool out = (SystemParametersInfoA(
    SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER,
    0,
    "C:\\test.bmp",
    SPIF_SENDCHANGE | SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE));
```

Where `test.bmp` does not exist.

Now, irrespective of whether the file exists or not, the `bool` return value is set to true.

If the file exists, the background is set to that file, as expected. If the file doesn't exist, the wallpaper is set to all black, and the function still returns true.

My application is set to use "Multi-Byte Character Set".  The same thing seems to happen with "Use Unicode Character Set", though.

Any ideas?

Comment: `"C:\wallpaper.bmp"` should be `"C:\\wallpaper.bmp"`. So that's one bug. If you now say that that's just a transcription error, you forgot to copy and paste and just re-typed the code, then maybe that's the problem with the code too.

Comment: Good spot.  That issue is not present in the code itself.  I've edited the question appropriately.

Comment: Sorry, I added a spurious comment based on reading things incorrectly. Now deleted.

Comment: Function returns `BOOL`, not `bool`. And I don't get what is wrong with the results you are getting. Wallpaper changes in both cases so result is not FALSE.

Comment: OK BOOL is correct, you're right.  I guess the wallpaper DOES change (to an all black screen) but surely the call should fail given that the file that I'm trying to use as the background does NOT exist?

Comment: Does it say in the documentation that it should fail if wallpaper file does not exist? I think this function simply updates settings values.

Comment: According to MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), "Note  When the SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER flag is used, SystemParametersInfo returns TRUE unless there is an error (like when the specified file doesn't exist)."

Comment: Isn't this a bit of a non-issue?  Why pass the name of a file that doesn't exist in the first place, when it's easy to check beforehand.

Comment: Suppose you call "if (SystemParametersInfoA(...))", then you want the return value to be correct.